# Converting a set of tweets into vectors for clustering

Tags: clustering, natural-language

I have a large set of tweets to which i plan to use cosine similarity to cluster the tweets. I found NLTK's GAAC to be good but how do i convert the tweets into vectors?

In `nltk.cluster.gaac.demo()` the data was passed as a vector  `[array([ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]), array([ 0.4472136 ,  0.89442719]), array([ 0.89442719,  0.4472136 ]), array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.5547002 ,  0.83205029]), array([ 0.9486833 ,  0.31622777])]`

For nltk gaac it says the input is vectors but i have plain text in the form of tweets.
How do i convert my set of tweets into vectors like this.

Answer (score 1):

Please read up on TF-IDF normalization of data.

That is what most likely was done to produce these vectors.

You can find details in any book on text mining, and on Wikipedia, and likely in the NLTK documentation.

Comment: I did tf-idf normalization for my data and got a csr matrix, but it's still not accepting it. Can you tell me how i should modify the the data so that it gets accepted as `vector` mentioned in the docs

Comment: @Kira csr matrices are sparse matrices [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix).  There should be a method called `.to_dense()` which will transform the matrix to a dense representation.  I think Stackoverflow is a better place to ask further questions about sparse/dense representations.